# PHP asynchronous page request code

Tags: php, email, asynchronous

i searched for a solution to make an asynchronous page request and found these lines of codes. (actually i editted a little bit)

```
function do_the_thing()
{
   $parts = parse_url("mail_sender.php");
   $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'], isset($parts['port']) ? $parts['port'] : 80, 
                   $errno, $errstr, 30);
   $out = "POST " . $parts['path'] . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
   $out.= "Host: " . $parts['host'] . "\r\n";
   $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
   $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
   fwrite($fp, $out);
   fclose($fp);
}
```

so i have a `mail_sender.php` that sends an e-mail AUTOMATICALLY but with this asynchronous call, it doesn't send anything. Am i missing somthing here? I am calling function in another page so page load continues without waiting the mail sending process. Only problem is, i seem to be unable to request the page or page is requested but doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the first two lines of your function, you have a problem:

`parse_url("mail_sender.php")` gives you an array with one element ([see example](http://codepad.org/iXXgm5nT)):

```
array(1) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(15) "mail_sender.php"
}
```

So you are calling `fsockopen` without the first - required - parameter.

Comment: i think i have corrected that mistake. is it ok if i give the url adress like this: "http://127.0.0.1/mail_sender.php" I tried this and now path and host values are returned but still nothing happens as i coded in mail_sender.php.